# Matching list of lists with other list of lists

Tags: haskell

Hey guys I have a question about matching lists

Given the list of lists:

```
Input List 1  = [[True],[False],[True],[[False]]
Input List 2 = [[Bob],[Rick],[Lee],[Bill]]
Input List 3 = [[1],[2],[3],[4]]
```

Then match the Booleans of list 1 with the other lists so this happens:

```
Input List 1 + Input List 2 = [[Bob],[Dead],[Lee],[Dead]]
Input List 1 + Input List 2 = [[1],[0],[3],[0]]
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why these are lists of lists, given that in your example all the inner lists have just one element?

Comment: too make it easier to read I guess but yeah they can have more than 1 element

Comment: Making it easier to read is not a good reason for using nested lists, as it makes everything far more complicated than necessary -- you would have to decide what to do with the other elements.

Comment: Would the input list of bools have to have to only include a single term? If the nested lists over values include multiple terms, should they all be made to the default value? What if a sublist in the list of bools includes several bools?

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, using nested lists here is unnecessary. Without them, all you need is `zipWith` and an appropriate combining function:

```
-- The first argument is the "dead" value. Note that this works with any type.
makeDead :: a -> Bool -> a -> a
makeDead dead b val
    | b = val
    | otherwise = dead
```

```
GHCi> :t zipWith
zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
GHCi> zipWith (makeDead "Dead") [True,False,True,False] ["Bob","Rick","Lee","Bill"] 
["Bob","Dead","Lee","Dead"]
```

Two variations on the theme. Firstly, if whether a value should be changed depends only on what the value is, then you can simply use `map`/`fmap`:

```
 -- Affects all names with 'i' as the second letter:
lethalLetter :: String -> String
lethalLetter name -> case name of
    (_:'i':_) -> "Dead"
    _ -> name
```

```
GHCi> fmap lethalLetter ["Bob", "Rick", "Lee", "Bill"]
["Bob","Dead","Lee","Dead"]
```

Secondly, you might prefer using `Maybe` to indicate deadness rather than using an arbitrary value (what if someone is actually called "Dead")?

```
makeDead' :: Bool -> a -> Maybe a
makeDead' b val
    | b = Just val
    | otherwise = Nothing
```

```
GHCi> zipWith makeDead' [True,False,True,False] ["Bob","Rick","Lee","Bill"] 
[Just "Bob",Nothing,Just "Lee",Nothing]
```

You can then use functions like `maybe`, `fromMaybe` and `catMaybes` (the latter two are in [`Data.Maybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html)) to get rid of the `Nothing`s however you feel like doing it:

```
GHCi> import Data.Maybe
GHCi> foo = zipWith makeDead' [True,False,True,False] ["Bob","Rick","Lee","Bill"]
GHCi> catMaybes foo
["Bob","Lee"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you change them to lists, as recommended by duplode, how about zipping together the two lists within a list comprehension, something like this:

```
[if flag then val else defaultVal  | (flag, val) <- zip(list1, list2)]
```

where `defaultVal` would have to be specified, but seems to be `Dead` and `0` for lists 2 and 3.

(I don't have access right now to Haskell, so the syntax may not be 100% there, but that's the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zipWith . zipWith :: (a -> b -> c) -> [[a]] -> [[b]] -> [[c]]` for matching lists of lists. For example:

```
import Data.Bool (bool)
kill deadVal = zipWith . zipWith $ bool (const deadVal) id

example = kill 0 [[True, False],[False,True]] [[1,2,3],[2]]
-- example = [[1,0],[0]]
```

Comment: It should be mentioned that this will zip each pair of matching inner lists, so that `kill "Dead" [[False,True]] [["James","Seamus"]]` will be `[["Dead","Seamus"]]`.

Comment: Yes. If one would expect otherwise I think it would be strange for the first list to be of type `[[Bool]]` instead of `[Bool]`.